# Designing a rails data schema to store snapshots of records with minimal repetition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, schema

I've built several web applications using the Ruby on Rails framework and have noticed a common design problem: due to the variable nature of some data, I often need to store a copy of a record with an event that occurs at a certain time.

For example, consider a store application with `products` and `orders` tables. When a user places an `Order`, the application should store copies of the `Product` records in the order so as to preserve the state of those products at the time of the order. This way, future modifications to a `Product` do not affect past orders.

I've typically solved this issue by introducing another table, say `order_products`, to store the products associated with an order. Each `OrderProduct` then `belongs_to` a base `Product`, but still stores copies of the attributes of the `Product`; I've written save callbacks to keep the two records' attributes synchronized until the user places the order, decoupling the records.

An issue with this design is duplication of data fields between the `products` and `order_products` tables; whenever I modify `Product` attributes, I must remember to modify `OrderProduct` attributes in the same way *and* update the save callbacks. Moreover, if a `Product` has associations that must be copied to the corresponding `OrderProduct`, repetition in tables starts to become unwieldy.

How can I build a schema to store these product "snapshots" associated with orders without or with minimal repetition?

(Note that I've provided concrete `products` and `orders` tables here for clarity, but I've run across the same abstract problem in several different scenarios.)

EDIT: Here's a similar question whose author suggests using history tables to store snapshots: [database structure for storing historical data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533451/database-structure-for-storing-historical-data). The accepted answer suggests the solution I presented above.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two designs that seem to minimize schema repetition in this scenario. Both solutions rely on [single table inheritance (STI)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html).

## Option 1

[image: STI option 1]

Let `RootProduct` and `OrderProduct` extend `Product` through STI (add a `type` column to the `products` table). Also add `order_id` and `root_id` columns to the `products` table. A `RootProduct` represents a standalone product (not associated with an order, `order_id = null` and `root_id = null`). An `OrderProduct`, by contrast, is associated with an order, and also the `RootProduct` from which it was created. When a user adds a `RootProduct` to an order, clone the product as an `OrderProduct` and save a reference to the root product in `root_id`. As long as the order remains unplaced, synchronize the attributes of the two product records, but decouple the records after the user places the order. The `OrderProduct` records serve as product snapshots.

## Option 2

[image: STI option 2]

As in option 1, let `RootProduct` and `FrozenProduct` extend `Product` through STI (add a `type` column to the `products` table). Also add a `root_id` column to the `products` table. A `RootProduct` represents the state of a product at the present point in time; a `FrozenProduct` represents a past snapshot of the product at the time when an order was placed. An `order_products` table is introduced to store the products associated with an order. Before an order is placed, each `OrderProduct` in the order links to a `RootProduct`. After an order is placed, each `OrderProduct` links to a `FrozenProduct` created by cloning the corresponding `RootProduct`.